# How to add spinner animation with element other than commandbutton?

Tags: visualforce, actionstatus

I am able to add spinner animation using apex:commandbutton.
Here is the reference to add spinner animation when commandbutton is clicked: 
[Popup "spinner" style apex:actionStatus](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65580/popup-spinner-style-apexactionstatus)

But how to add spinner animation using element and onclick listener?
Below is the example code of element onclick event:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="pnlSearchResults" style="margin:10px;height:350px;overflow-Y:auto;" layout="block">
    <apex:pageBlock id="searchResults">
        <apex:pageMessages id="errors"/>
        <ul id="products" class="list clearfix products">
            <apex:repeat id="repeatdata" var="dt" value="{!resultList}">
                <li class="clearfix" onclick="showDetail('{!dt.bookingId}', '{!searchString}');">
                    <div class="left">
                        <img src="{!$Resource.jquery_list_grid_switcher + '/images/products/list-default-thumb.png'}" alt="default thumb" class="thumb" />
                        <h3>{!dt.name}</h3><br/>
                        <span class="meta">{!dt.phone}</span><br/>
                        <span class="meta">{!dt.email}</span><br/>
                        <span class="meta"><c:TimestampConverter componentValue="{!dt.timestamp}" /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <span class="price">{!dt.amount}</span>
                        <div class="bookid">{!dt.bookingId}</div>
                        <div class="tripType">{!dt.tripType}</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </apex:repeat>
        </ul>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

javascript:

```
function showDetail(bookingId, lastQuery) {
    window.location = "/apex/DetailView?bookingId=" + bookingId + "&lastQuery=" + lastQuery + "&action=detail";
}
```

I want to add spinner animation when the `<li>` tag is clicked.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`actionFunction`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm#!):

```
<apex:actionFunction name="search" action="{!search}" status="searchStatus" />
<apex:actionStatus id="searchStatus" />
```

This will add a javascript function called "search" which your javascript can call, and when you call it it will cause the "search" controller method to execute and also show the searchStatus `actionStatus`.