# Show Spinner while the visualforce page is loading for the first time

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom button of the type visual force page on the standard record detail page. When I click on the button a visualforce page opens up that displays all the account records. But this visualforce page is taking time to fetch the data and display it on the vf page. Now I need to show a spinner or a loading icon on click of the custom button on the standard record detail page so that the end-user can understand that the page is being loaded. In the picture below "Display Accounts" is my custom button on the standard record detail page which onclick displays a list of accounts. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Can you check this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65580/popup-spinner-style-apexactionstatus/65582#65582